# jq: index/1 not working when element is an array

Tags: arrays, json, indexing, jq

```
echo "[[{\"t\":4}]]" | jq 'index(.[0])'
```

I was expecting this to return 0.
Instead it's returning null.
Index works fine for arrays with scalars only but once there are nested arrays it returns null.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the jq manual, there is a hint about the semantics of `index` under the heading `indices`. In brief, the seemingly buggy behavior is actually a “feature”.  That is, the following illustrates the intended behavior:

```
$ jq 'index([1,2])'
[1,2]
0
$ jq 'index([[1,2]])'
[[1,2]]
0
$
```

So to search for a JSON entity X, using `index([X])` is always safe. Unfortunately, because of the way `index` is currently implemented, it is not as efficient as it could (should) be, but that’s a different topic.

However it's worth knowing about `.[[X]]` and `IN/1`.

#### .[[X]]

A little-known fact is that postfix square-brackets provide "index-of" functionality:

```
$ jq -nc '[1,2,30,3,3][[3]]'
[3,4]

$ jq -nc '[[1],2,30,3][[1]]'
[]

$ jq -nc '[[1],2,30,3][[[1]]]'
[0]

$ jq -nc '[{a:1},2,30,3][[ {a:1} ]]'
[0]
```

So to recover the least index of X in the input array:

```
.[[X]][0]
```

As with `index/1`, this returns null if X is not in the input array:

```
$ jq -n '[1,2,3][ [4] ][0]'
null
```

#### IN/1

The “master” version of jq has a pair of straightforward stream-oriented filters (named `IN`) for checking whether an item is in a stream.  Here is an efficient def of `IN/1` which can be used if your jq has `first/1`:

```
def IN(s): . as $in | first( if (s == $in) then true else empty end ) // false;
```

Here `s` is the stream to search.

Answer (score 2):

Because apparently `index` takes a subsequence of elements to find, with a scalar being a special case equivalent to an one element sequence.

Compare the three cases:

```
echo "[0,2,0,3,0,6,0,2]" | jq 'index(2)'
echo "[0,2,0,3,0,6,0,2]" | jq 'index([2])'
echo "[0,2,0,3,0,6,0,2]" | jq 'index([2,0])'
```

They all return 1.

So in your case it is trying to find a single element subsequence consisting of an object in a list that contains a list (and not directly an object).